# Native SeekbarPreference as presented in Material Design

Tags: android, android-preferences

After reading the settings part of the Material Design available [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/settings.html#settings-usage), I came across the following screenshot:

[image]

The 3 first preferences presented are seekbars but I cannot find anything about it, even in the support libraries.

Am I missing something here or Google just created a custom preference that is not available yet?

Answer (score 0):

[Developer docs explain how to achieve custom views in Settings.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Custom)

TL;DR

1. You need to create your custom layout file having ImageView, TextView and SeekBar wrapped inside a LinearLayout.
2. Then you write a class which extends Preference implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener and override all the necessary methods to listen to SeekBar changes.
3. In the Preference XML file add your custom class as a tag and you will see a similar UI.

Comment: My question was not about how to create a custom preference, my question is why Google does not provide this component natively since they display it everywhere in the documentation. That does not make sense to let all the developers create their own SeekBarPreference, it should be a default component.

Comment: I'm not sure about Google's reason for not making this available by default. I answered this question so that someone somewhere can find this information useful and save some time. I'm happy your issue is already taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

SeekBarPreference is actually natively present in Android and is not a custom class that needs to be implemented.
You can see it in the Palette (highlighted).[image: SwitchPreference]